# Expo build failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo

I'm currently trying to build my expo app for android with `eas build --platform android --profile preview`, however it results in a fail:

```
    FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
     1. Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'. > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
     2. java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
```

Further up in the logs, I get various problems related to this bundelRelesaeJSAndAssets for packages

```
     - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:mergeReleaseShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency.
```

I have seen solutions for this problem, however they all have been used in react native projects and them using something like `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`, but I'm not sure how to apply such a solution to an expo managed project.

Building it with the development client works.
If anyone can point me into any direction I would be happy, with a problem like this I'm not quite sure where to start.

Full(-ish) logs:

```
    Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
    Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
    10
    %.
    20%.
    30%.
    40%.
    50%.
    60%.
    70%.
    80%.
    90%.
    100%
    Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!
    Here are the highlights of this release:
     - Support for Java 18
     - Support for building with Groovy 4
    - Much more responsive continuous builds
     - Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution
    For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html
    To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
    Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
    > Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
    > Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources
    ...
    > Configure project :expo-updates-interface
    WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
    > Configure project :expo
    Using expo modules
      - expo-application (5.0.1)
      - expo-constants (14.0.2)
      - expo-dev-client (2.0.1)
      - expo-dev-launcher (2.0.2)
      - expo-dev-menu (2.0.2)
      - expo-device (5.0.0)
      - expo-error-recovery (4.0.1)
      - expo-file-system (15.1.1)
      - expo-font (11.0.1)
      - expo-json-utils (0.4.0)
      - expo-keep-awake (11.0.1)
      - expo-localization (14.0.0)
      - expo-manifests (0.4.0)
      - expo-modules-core (1.1.1)
      - expo-secure-store (12.0.0)
      - expo-splash-screen (0.17.5)
    WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
    WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33
    This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32
    This warning can be suppressed by adding
        android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
    to this project's gradle.properties
    The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
    use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
    Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
    License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
    Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
    "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.
    Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3
    "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.
    "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.
    Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
    License for package Android SDK Platform 33 accepted.
    Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)".
    "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" ready.
    Installing Android SDK Platform 33 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-33
    "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" complete.
    "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" finished.
    The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build. 
    This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
    Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
    If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
    See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
    The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core'
    The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build. 
    This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
    Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
    If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
    See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
    The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':react-native-screens', ':stripe_stripe-react-native'
    > Task :expo-application:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :expo-constants:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :expo-application:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :expo-constants:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :expo-application:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :expo-dev-client:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :expo-dev-client:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :expo-constants:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    ...
    > Task :expo-font:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :expo-dev-menu:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :expo-json-utils:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :expo-keep-awake:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
    Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
      - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':expo-application:compileReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
      ...
      
      - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
      ...
      - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':stripe_stripe-react-native:packageReleaseAssets' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
      - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':stripe_stripe-react-native:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
    > Task :expo-json-utils:generateReleaseResValues
    ...
    > Task :expo-updates-interface:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseResValues
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseResources
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateReleaseResValues
    > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateReleaseResources
    > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :react-native-screens:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :react-native-screens:generateReleaseResValues
    > Task :react-native-screens:generateReleaseResources
    > Task :expo-splash-screen:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :react-native-svg:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :react-native-svg:generateReleaseResValues
    > Task :react-native-svg:generateReleaseResources
    > Task :react-native-svg:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:generateReleaseResValues
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:generateReleaseResources
    > Task :react-native-screens:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :expo:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :expo-dev-launcher:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :expo-application:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:packageReleaseResources
    > Task :expo-application:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :expo-constants:extractDeepLinksRelease
    ...
    > Task :expo-file-system:processReleaseManifest
    /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-file-system/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:8:9-10:20 Warning:
        provider#expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:8 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
    > Task :expo-json-utils:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :expo-font:processReleaseManifest
    ...
    > Task :expo-secure-store:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :expo-modules-core:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :expo-splash-screen:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :expo-localization:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :expo-updates-interface:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :expo-splash-screen:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :expo-secure-store:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :expo-updates-interface:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :react-native-screens:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :react-native-svg:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:extractDeepLinksRelease
    > Task :react-native-screens:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :react-native-svg:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:processReleaseManifest
    > Task :expo-application:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-constants:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-dev-client:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-dev-menu-interface:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-device:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-dev-launcher:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-file-system:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-error-recovery:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-font:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-json-utils:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-keep-awake:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-localization:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-dev-menu:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-manifests:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-secure-store:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-updates-interface:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :react-native-svg:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    > Task :react-native-screens:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
    warning: the transform cache was reset.
                    Welcome to Metro v0.72.3
                  Fast - Scalable - Integrated
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:parseReleaseLocalResources
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:compileReleaseLibraryResources
    > Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    > Task :expo-application:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    ...
    > Task :expo-dev-menu:parseReleaseLocalResources
    > Task :expo-dev-menu-interface:parseReleaseLocalResources
    > Task :expo-dev-menu-interface:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:javaPreCompileRelease
    > Task :expo-json-utils:parseReleaseLocalResources
    > Task :expo-json-utils:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :expo-manifests:parseReleaseLocalResources
    > Task :expo-manifests:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :expo-dev-menu:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :expo-updates-interface:parseReleaseLocalResources
    > Task :expo-updates-interface:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :expo-dev-launcher:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :expo-device:parseReleaseLocalResources
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :expo-device:generateReleaseRFile
    > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
    /home/expo/workingdir/build/babel.config.js:2
    export default function (api) {
    ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
        at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
        at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
        at parseSync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parse.js:41:72)
        at Object.transform (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/src/index.js:194:11)
        at transformJSWithBabel (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:399:45)
        at Object.transform (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:572:18)
        at transformFile (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.flow.js:82:36)
        at Object.transform (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.flow.js:55:10)
        at execFunction (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:137:17)
        at execHelper (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:116:5)
    info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
    [stderr] 
    error index.ts: Unexpected token 'export'.
    > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
    > Task :expo-error-recovery:parseReleaseLocalResources
    > Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
    [stderr] 
    Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [stderr] 
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [stderr] 
    Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [stderr] 
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    > Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:compileReleaseKotlin
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardChangedEvent.kt: (6, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardChangedEvent.kt: (8, 235): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardChangedEvent.kt: (13, 42): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardChangedEvent.kt: (14, 21): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardFocusEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardFocusEvent.kt: (7, 92): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardFocusEvent.kt: (12, 42): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardFocusEvent.kt: (13, 21): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardFormCompleteEvent.kt: (6, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardFormCompleteEvent.kt: (8, 200): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardFormCompleteEvent.kt: (13, 42): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/CardFormCompleteEvent.kt: (14, 21): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/FormCompleteEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/FormCompleteEvent.kt: (7, 112): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/FormCompleteEvent.kt: (12, 42): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/FormCompleteEvent.kt: (13, 21): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/StripeSdkModule.kt: (63, 21): 'getParcelableExtra(String!): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/pushprovisioning/AddToWalletCompleteEvent.kt: (4, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/pushprovisioning/AddToWalletCompleteEvent.kt: (6, 102): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/pushprovisioning/AddToWalletCompleteEvent.kt: (11, 42): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/pushprovisioning/AddToWalletCompleteEvent.kt: (12, 21): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
    w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/pushprovisioning/TapAndPayProxy.kt: (29, 39): Unchecked cast: Any! to Task<List<Any>>
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
    You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
    Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
    217 actionable tasks: 217 executed
    [stderr] 
    FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
    [stderr] 
    1: Task failed with an exception.
    [stderr] 
    -----------
    [stderr] 
    * What went wrong:
    [stderr] 
    Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
    [stderr] 
    > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    [stderr] 
    * Try:
    [stderr] 
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    [stderr] 
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    [stderr] 
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [stderr] 
    ==============================================================================
    [stderr] 
    2: Task failed with an exception.
    [stderr] 
    -----------
    [stderr] 
    * What went wrong:
    [stderr] 
    java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
    [stderr] 
    * Try:
    [stderr] 
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    [stderr] 
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    [stderr] 
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [stderr] 
    ==============================================================================
    [stderr] 
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [stderr] 
    BUILD FAILED in 3m 18s
    Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

Comment: To me it looks like the issue resides in the babel.config.js more than task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage.'

Comment: My babel.config is kind of barebone at this point, mostly just to setup abs. paths
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
export default function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo", "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
    plugins: [
      "nativewind/babel",
      "react-native-paper/babel",
      [
        "module-resolver",
        ...
      ],
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
       ...
      ],
    ],
  };
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the issue resides in the babel.config.js more than task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage.'

Try and use the module.exports syntax, e.g.:

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: []
  };
};
```

Comment: Awesome this was the solution. Thank you